# Chromium-based browser with out-of-the-box password sync

Tags: android, web-browser, chromium

I am looking for a Chromium-based browser which support sync out of the box.

I want to sync:

- Browser history
- Bookmarks
- Passwords

With "sync" I mean "sync between desktop (Linux) and Android".

Required Features:

- the browser needs to be based upon Chromium
- the browser needs to be open source

Comment: An alternative solution would be https://www.xbrowsersync.org/. This open source tool provides syncing for several browsers

Comment: An open source web browser may be the best for trustworthiness, but maintaining a web browser and keeping it secure requires a lot of man power. The only organization I know that has enough power to provide a secure browser with recent security fixes is Mozilla but of course Firefox is not Chromium based. So on open source Chromium based web browser you would in my opinion sacrifice security for trustworthiness.

Comment: I switched from Firefox to Chromium several months ago, and I don't want to go back. Why should I not trust chromium?

Comment: I never said that you distrust Chromium. In your questions you asked for an open source Chromium based web browser. Based on this it is clear that you don't trust Chrome (has everything you want except open source) because otherwise you would not ask for an open source based web browser.

Comment: 1. you never explain what is the problem with Chrome - which already has that. 2.  What is the motivation to reject non "out-of-the-box" solutions? Bitwarden is completely open-source, integrates with any browser, including mobile OSs.
---- can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Lockszmith Chrome is not open source. I have no clue what kind of tracking Google does. On the other hand I prefer Chromium to Firefox. About Bitwarden: this is not only about passwords. It is about browser-history, too.

Comment: I've ditched chromium practically because I couldn't trust any of the forks to be up-to-date enough to be safe, and the main to be 'clean', so I completely understand where you are coming from.

I think this list is where you should search for your solution:
https://awesomeopensource.com/projects/chromium/android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated my answer**, as you changed the focus from password sync to a more general sync.

I'm going on a limb here, and suggest that an open-source chromium based solution with an out-of-the-box password sync doesn't exist to sync Linux and Android. (One of the reason I abandoned chromium based browsers myself as much as I can)
The most complete list of chromium based android projects I know of is probably [this one](https://awesomeopensource.com/projects/chromium/android).

As for password sync, I would suggest a different approach: [Bitwarden](https://www.bitwarden.com) which is not only open-source, it can be completely self-hosted.

Desktop browser integration is done via an extension, and Android integration is on the OS level via the App's auto-fill option.

If you are interested in the self-hosted solution, other than the official solution, there is the slimmer server implementation of [vaultwarden](https://github.com/dani-garcia/vaultwarden).

From my personal experience I can tell you, I've had this installed for a couple of years now, and have my family members (and a few friends) using it as the only password vault.
Doesn't require to be a techie to use, integration into Android UI works very well with most browsers and most sites.

As for browser history - that would definitely need some native browser solution - but I'm unclear here - I personally but very little effort into this area.

If you run a nextcloud instance, I think [floccus](https://floccus.org/) is a great option for bookmark sync, but then again - I don't think it solves you the android client issue.